# Chart.js radar tooltip displaying too many values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So I am working on a chart.js project for a client and one of the charts they want is a radar chart of all their metrics. The image below is the sample chart

[image]

The issue I'm having is with the tooltips. In the default mode everything works fine except for the very center. There are several values that are zero and when I hover over them it displays all of them. What I need is for it to only display one.

[image]

I tried setting the mode to 'single' even though it is depreciated and that worked. However, that brought a new problem.

```
options: {
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'single'
  }
}
```

When I hover over an element, the entire dataset highlights and the rest disappear. Its kind of hard to tell but the two images below are highlighting two different datasets, but since the points overlap slightly, the tooltip value is not updating

[image]
[image]

I am using the latest version of chart.js (2.9.3) as of posting this

Comment: Show the code that cause the buggy hint.

Comment: I updated the question, but its just a single line "mode: 'single'; " causing it

Comment: When they all have the value 0, how should it decide to show which one? Couldn't you modify the tooltip and make it custom?

Comment: Here is is a link https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

Comment: Realistically it would probably just show the first one when they are all zero. I'm not sure making a custom tooltip would work, because even though they appear as one, I believe all of the 0 values count as separate tooltips